# Access lines from a text file on a network

Tags: batch-file

I need to create a batch file that reads computer names and saves in a text file on a network location. I have tested the loop below and it works locally by changing the location to read my desktop.

Putting the .txt file there, and had it echo the contents. Works fine.  When I change the location to a network one, it says the file cannot be found.

```
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (\\lanlocation.com\filepath\filex\IT\"IT Scripts"\Deployment\computer.txt) do pushd \\%%A\c$
pause
```

I've run into issues before with a space in the network path name causing issues, but I don't believe that's the case here as the error reads off the entire correct path before saying "file cannot be found".  Lastly...yes. The file is there and I'm referencing the right name.

Also, if anyone has a good resource for some batch information, I'd be very appreciative if you would share a link or name of a book.

Thanks!

Comment: I think `\"` escapes the quote. Simply put the quotes around the entire file path `"\\lan............txt"` and add `usebackq` inside the options: `for /F "tokens=* usebackq"` to treat the quoted string as a file name.

Comment: @wOxxOm , tried what you've suggested, but no luck.  I added the suggestions above.  After doing so, the error acted as I'd seen in the past, not recognizing the space in the file path.  The error (paraphrasing) said "cannot find the file at \\lanlocation.com\...\"IT.  To fix that, I had to wrap the path containing a space in double quotes. That, unfortunately, brings me back to the same issue.

Comment: The error message in your comment suggests you have kept the original quotes around `IT Scripts`. Remove them and redo my suggestion.

Comment: First do a `pushd` to the entire path in quotes, then read the file via the `for /F` with just its name.

Comment: @wOxxOm That was it!  Added the usebackq, quoted the entire path and removed quotes from the "IT Scripts" portion. Returned it all for me. Thanks!